# describeLoadBalancers does not show classic load balancers

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get a list of load balancer using the AWS Java API.

```
    AmazonElasticLoadBalancing elbClient = AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient
            .builder()
            .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();
    DescribeLoadBalancersResult result = elbClient.describeLoadBalancers(
            new DescribeLoadBalancersRequest());
    for (LoadBalancer lb : result.getLoadBalancers()) {
        System.out.println(lb.getLoadBalancerName());
    }
```

The call works, but only the new application load balancers are listed. I don't see any of the classic load balancers. My credentials are unrestricted.

How do I get a handle to classic load balancers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there are two APIs for Elastic Load Balancing.  The javadoc for [AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancing/AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.html) provides a hint:

> This reference covers the 2015-12-01 API, which supports Application Load Balancers. The 2012-06-01 API supports Classic Load Balancers.

For the code below, the commented out code will NOT print out classic load balancers, but the uncommented out code will:

```
/*
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.AmazonElasticLoadBalancing;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.model.DescribeLoadBalancersRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.model.DescribeLoadBalancersResult;
*/
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancing;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.model.DescribeLoadBalancersRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.model.DescribeLoadBalancersResult;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AwsTestIT
{
    /*
    @Test
    public void testGetLoadBalancers()
    {
        AmazonElasticLoadBalancing amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient = AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder
            .defaultClient();
        DescribeLoadBalancersResult result =
            amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.describeLoadBalancers(new DescribeLoadBalancersRequest());
        result.getLoadBalancers().stream().forEach(loadBalancer -> System.out
            .println("loadBalancer = " + loadBalancer));
    }
    */

    @Test
    public void testGetLoadBalancers()
    {
        AmazonElasticLoadBalancing amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient = AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder
            .defaultClient();
        DescribeLoadBalancersResult result =
            amazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.describeLoadBalancers(new DescribeLoadBalancersRequest());
        result.getLoadBalancerDescriptions().stream().forEach(loadBalancer -> System.out
            .println("loadBalancer = " + loadBalancer));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I made it work using an old AWS SDK, like this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing/1.11.158

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 separate APIs: one for classic ELBs, and one for ALBs.

The one you're using is probably the "v2" API and will return only ALBs.

You'll need to use the "v1" API to retrieve classic ELBs.

For example, in the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/), there is `aws elb` and `aws elbv2`.